# How to run hybrid docker swarm mode (linux and windows) in Azure?

Tags: windows, azure, docker, containers, swarm

I'm looking to run a number of applications in containers (win and linux) in azure in a large docker swarm. Have it running locally (swarm mode), but I'm struggling to find good info re azure. Should I go with:

*) Container Service/ swarm (not sure if this support windows containers yet)

*) Container Service/ kubernetes (apparently has windows containers in preview)

*) Something else? eg. should I just deploy a batch of vm's in a vnet and roll my own?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-swarm-mode-walkthrough

Run with the `--windows` flag as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acs?view=azure-cli-latest

Comment: Thanks for the response Brandon, I've checked this out, and from the az acs create documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acs?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acs_create) looks like only docker ce is available in acs for windows:

--orchestrator-type {Custom, DCOS, DockerCE, Kubernetes, Swarm}